# QT scrollbar can't reach bottom of window

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface

I'm working on a piece of software, that utilizes QT and have run into a problem. In one of the windows: [The scrollbar exhausts its range before reaching the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efGVR.png). I can still get to the lower contents of the window by resizing it, but that's obviously clunky. How do I make it so the scrollbar's lowest position corresponds to the page's lowest point?

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue once because I accidentally put a custom widget that included a QScrollArea with scrollbar policy always set to "always off" inside of another QScrollArea. The resulting behavior was the same as the one you are experiencing.